# .jcp equivalent for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, file-extension, jcreator

for one of my labs I have in my CS2 class at school, JCreator is installed on the school's computers with a 4.x version, I'm more of an eclipse person myself, I even use it at school in place of JCreator, but the file extension `.jcp` from what I know is a JCreator related file extension. What can I do to make a folder of files compatible with eclipse, which I use at home as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse identifies its projects by using two files namely `.classpath` and `.project`. As long as you can export those along with the project files and structure, you should be able to import a project into another eclipse instance.

I am not sure JCreator can create those files for you but I am sure that every eclipse project generates these files.

You can keep the JCreator specific files in the project folder(s), eclipse will ignore all the files that it cannot process/understand. The problem will be how to keep the libraries you are using in sync in both IDE environments as you edit your project.

You might want to re-factor that out to a build management tool like `ant/buildr/maven`

Comment: eclipse does in fact, create `.classpath` and `.project` files when going file->new->Java Project. However, wouldn't all that matters is that I be able to edit the `.java` files?

Comment: @tech_geek23 I am not sure I understand your comment?

Comment: after reading it back, I realized it didn't make a ton of sense either... more of an agreement statement... put it this way, if I keep the `.jcp` file in the folder and still have the `.classpath` and `.project` files there as well, that'd make it cross-compatible, right?